# Capacitor bank for delayed solenoid closure

Tags: solenoid, supercapacitor

I have a 24 VDC solenoid valve plumbed in line with a 24 VDC motorized ball valve transporting water. These are redundant because it is critical not to have a valve fail and cause an overfill event.

The MBV has a built in auto return function which shuts the valve off when 24 VDC ceases to be applied. To prevent water hammer I would like to keep the solenoid powered for 5-6 seconds after the 24 VDC stops being applied.

My thought was to use 6 5.5 V, 4 F super capacitors in series to achieve a 33 V rating and a total capacitance of 0.666 F.

I'm wondering what kind of protection I need to build into the circuit. Is there a better way to accomplish the goal of keeping the solenoid energized for 5-6 seconds after power stops being applied to the circuit?

Comment: Data sheets for the devices you mention are required.

Comment: You can buy relays with built-in timer functions that will do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Finbarr Can you provide a link? I've not seen relays that delay after power is removed.

Comment: Something like [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/timer-relays/8966822)

Comment: You might try a small 24V UPS paired with a timer relay or switch.  This will give you better control of the "off" time delay and the problem with inrush current charging the big capacitors.

Comment: I should add the solenoid is 24vdc and draws about 800ma while operating. Since I need it energized for at least 5 seconds I need about .026 watt hour of storage, or 93 joules. More joules is ok.

Comment: No data sheets but here are links to the specs for the valves:

MBV: https://ussolid.com/motorized-ball-valve-1-2-stainless-steel-ball-valve-with-manual-function-full-port-9-24v-ac-dc-and-2-wire-auto-return-setup-by-u-s-solid.html
Solenoid: https://ussolid.com/u-s-solid-electric-solenoid-valve-1-2-24v-dc-solenoid-valve-stainless-steel-body-normally-closed-viton-seal.html

Comment: I think a timer relay powered by a supplemental power supply (which could be mains or a UPS as @John Birckhead suggested) would be a good approach.

Comment: Why a UPS? The 24V supply is surely still available?

Comment: Both valves are in a small enclosure 10 feet away from the 24vdc power source. Space is very limited so 6 supercaps the size of CR2032's would fit fine. Currently I only have 2 conductors going to the box, I could use the timer relay with a 3rd conductor for the solenoid. I'm still curious why the supercap setup could not work or isnt recommended.